# Contentpane query for calling an html page

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have a **tab_dojo.html** page in my project-space which I am calling using href function of content-pane from a jsp page in the same project . Here **tab_dojo.html** has a tree structure in it. But when I am clicking on the tab the page is getting called with the heading of the tree message displayed while preview but the tree is not showing up.

Can someone say why is it happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="screen">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style>
.screen {height: 900px; width: 1200px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
</script>
</head>
<body class="screen tundra">

<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:2000px;height:1800px">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="View1 tree" href="tab_dojo.html">Site view</div>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="View2 tree"selected="true">vuew2</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Have you checked if the tab_dojo.html is correctly linked? This could be the reason that it does not work.Regards

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem with the pasted code, but remember that you have to `require` the dijit Tree module, and anything else you're using in tab_dojo.html. Perhaps if you paste that code as well, it'll be easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: perfect, it worked for me...included my html in jsp and called it..It wasnt correctly linked, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach for future readers. Thanks all for your suggestions include the html in jsp and call it in this way it will work

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width:900px;height:1200px">
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  title="Test"  >
<jsp:include page="your.jsp" />
</div> </div>
```